# How to align several pictures in LR?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, image-alignment, auto-alignment

Let's say I have several pictures of relatively similar objects (in my case it is boxes of different size). The angle of view shows three sides of a box:
[image]

This pictures intended to be placed on the internet site so I would like to have all those boxes have the same angle and same left-most position.

I foresee that doing this manually without any additional software help will take a lot of time :( I will better put some strings on my monitor :)))

I'm coming to the question: is there any tools helping to align the pictures one to another?

Comment: Could you maybe post another photo that you would like to align to the first one? Because now it's not clear how the individual photos are misaligned exactly. Is it only the position, or are the boxes also rotated differently w.r.t. the camera?

Comment: Seems like this is a case where some setup work beforehand might save you some time on the back end.  Can you fix the location of your camera and mark your set so the boxes start in the same place?

Answer (score 1):

Why would doing this manually take a lot of time?  Place a camera on a tripod at a fixed place.  Put down two pieces of tape to define the front and left side placement of the box.  This will ensure that all boxes have the same orientation and left most starting point.  Place each box on the mark and take the photo.  This is far easier than trying to adjust later in software.

Answer (score 0):

The change in angle all but requires the use of panorama software such as Hugin because only(?) these programs have the features you need. You don't have to stitch the results as there's a flag to output single images.

Comment: you need a full 3D representation to change the angle in software. 2D warping only works on planes.